# Python Word Subsets

Tags: python

I am looking to build a list of words (three letters or more) that make up a large list of six-letter words. I was wondering if there was a cleaner or more efficient way to loop through the characters to build these subsets.

The top of this program (not posted) takes two `.txt` files - one containing the list of 6-letter words and one containing the Scrabble Dictionary (used to determine what is a real word).

The main core of my code is below. I loop through each character of the word, making sure indexes don't repeat and then build each word subset. I then sort the list on length and convert it into a string via `.join` to feed into another app I am writing for "subset guessing".

```
# Define Dictionary Lookup Function
def isDictionaryWord(word):
    if (word.lower().strip()) in listDictionary:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def createSubsets(word):
    print 'Starting Word Subset - ' + word
    starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
    tempOutput = []

    ## 1-Letter Word Loop
    for c in range(0, len(word)):

        ## 2-Letter Word Loop (skip)
        for d in range(0, len(word)):
            if (c != d):

                    ## 3-Letter Word Loop
                    for e in range(0, len(word)):
                        if (c != e) and (d != e):
                            threeLetterWord = word[c] + word[d] + word[e]
                            if isDictionaryWord(threeLetterWord) and (threeLetterWord not in tempOutput):
                                tempOutput.append(threeLetterWord)
                                #print threeLetterWord

                            ## 4-Letter Word Loop
                            for f in range(0, len(word)):
                                if (c != f) and (d != f) and (e != f):
                                    fourLetterWord = word[c] + word[d] + word[e] + word[f]
                                    if isDictionaryWord(fourLetterWord) and (fourLetterWord not in tempOutput):
                                        tempOutput.append(fourLetterWord)
                                        #print fourLetterWord

                                    ## 5-Letter Word Loop
                                    for g in range(0, len(word)):
                                        if (c != g) and (d != g) and (e != g) and (f != g):
                                            fiveLetterWord = word[c] + word[d] + word[e] + word[f] + word[g]
                                            if isDictionaryWord(fiveLetterWord) and (fiveLetterWord not in tempOutput):
                                                tempOutput.append(fiveLetterWord)
                                                #print fiveLetterWord

    endtime = datetime.datetime.now()


    ## Sort Array by Length for Game Purposes & Convert to String
    tempOutput.sort(key = len)
    tempOutputStr = word + ": " + ", ".join(tempOutput)

    print 'Total Time Taken (s) - ' + str((endtime - starttime).total_seconds())
    print 'Total Subset Words   - ' + str(len(tempOutput) - 1) + '\n'
    print 'Temp Output Array    - ' + str(tempOutput) + '\n'
    print 'Temp Output String   - ' + tempOutputStr
    print '========================================'

    # Print tempOutputStr
    fOut.write(tempOutputStr + '\n')



# Loop through all 6-letter words and create subsets
for word in listSix:
    createSubsets(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some comments, in no particular order:

- You can simplify the definition of `isDictionaryWord()`:

  ```
  def isDictionaryWord(word):
      return word.lower().strip() in listDictionary
  ```

  although as it stands, that won’t work because `listDictionary` isn’t defined.

  Speaking of that function, this comment:

  ```
  # Define Dictionary Lookup Function
  ```

  tells me nothing I couldn’t learn from reading the next line. It’s superfluous and should be removed.
- Have a read of [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), particularly with regards to variable naming. Python uses snake_case for most variables, with CamelCase reserved for classes only.
- Since you’re using Python 2.x (I can tell from the print statements), it’s more efficient to use `xrange()` instead of `range()` – this creates a memory-efficient iterator rather than creating a list, which can make your code much faster over large ranges.
- You could tidy up some of your checks by making `tempOutput` a set instead of a list, then uniqueness is enforced by Python. Your innermost checks become more like:

  ```
  if is_dictionary_word(three_letter_word):
      temp_output.add(three_letter_word)
  ```
- Rather than writing out the loops explicitly, I’d suggest looking at the [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations). This contains some very fast functions for doing big loops. For example, your check for three-letter words reduces to the following:

  ```
  import itertools

  temp_output = []

  for tmp_word in itertools.permutations(word.lower(), r=3):
      if is_dictionary_word(tmp_word):
          temp_output.append(tmp_word)
  ```

  You can add similarly simple loops to get the four and five-letter words.

  This has a few other benefits:

  - This approach enforces uniqueness, so we can use a list (which preserves ordering) without needing to check if a word is already there.
  - The array is already sorted by length of the word, with the shortest words first.
  - By lowercasing the main word once, we can speed up our calls to `is_dictionary_word` by getting rid of the `.lower()` and `.strip()` calls.
- There’s too much code in the `createSubsets()` function. That function includes:

  - Printing debug code about what it’s doing, and how long it took
  - Finding a list of subset words
  - Writing that list to a file

  It would be better if each of those tasks were handled by separate functions – this would allow you to reuse code more easily among different parts of your code.